# Could not load file or assembly 'WinRTXamlToolkit'

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I want to use some charts in my `Windows Phone 8.1` application. So, following [this](http://eren.ws/2013/10/15/using-graphs-and-charts-in-windows-store-apps-boredom-challenge-day-11/) tutorial I have done the following:

1. I have installed the following packages:

   [image]
2. I have the following `XAML`:

   ```
   <Page xmlns:Charting="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting" 
   x:Class="MST_61462004_E3T02.MainPage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:MST_61462004_E3T02"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d"
   Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

   <Grid>

       <Charting:Chart x:Name="PieChart"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Margin="100,100,0,0"
                       Width="400"
                       Height="400">
           <Charting:PieSeries Margin="0"
                               IndependentValuePath="Name"
                               DependentValuePath="Amount"
                               IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
       </Charting:Chart>


   </Grid>
   ```

But I get the following error:

> Error 1   Could not load file or assembly 'WinRTXamlToolkit,
>   Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

I am using `windows runtime` blank project.

Could anyone point what is causing the error?

Comment: Does it repro on other machines?

Comment: Does your project have references to both dlls? Can you try it again on a new project? Can you confirm that both the dlls are in your packages folder?

Comment: @FilipSkakun I have delete this project and create new one and this time ti works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the symptoms - most likely a network issue or nuget/vs bug caused a problem with file missing from the package.

It always helps to try to reproduce a problem.